# Empty fileset after copy within a macrodef in Ant

Tags: ant

I've been banging my head against the wall on this all day!

In the below macro I always end up with an empty fileset:

```
<macrodef name="gzipAndUploadFileset">
    <attribute name="mimeType"/>
    <element name="fileset"/>
    <sequential>

        <delete dir="${staging}" />

        <copy toDir="${staging}">
            <fileset refid="fileset"/>
        </copy>

        <fileset id="sfs" dir="${staging}" includes="**/*"/>

        <echo>
            ${staging}
            ${ant.refid:sfs}
        </echo>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

The `staging` property is set, and is populated with 50-odd files after the copy operation.

This is what is echo'd:

```
    [echo]              /path/to/staging
    [echo]              ${ant.refid:sfs}
```

Which I think means the "sfs" fileset is empty. I added in the `includes` to see if that explicit setting picked up the files... but no.

I tried putting in a sleep after the copy, in case the Copy task doesn't block. Didn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** name your macro element with the same name as an existing ant task. I suggest you rename `fileset` element into `files` for instance :

```
<macrodef name="gzipAndUploadFileset">
    <attribute name="mimeType"/>
    <element name="files"/>

    <sequential>

    <delete dir="${staging}" />

    <copy toDir="${staging}">
        <files/>
    </copy>

    <fileset id="sfs" dir="${staging}" includes="**/*"/>

    <echo>
        ${staging}
        ${ant.refid:sfs}
    </echo>
</sequential>
```

You can see `files` element as a placeholder which is replaced by its content when executing the macro (see [macroDef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html)).
Now you can call your macro like this :

```
<target name="testmacro">
    <gzipAndUploadFileset mimeType="application/x-gzip">
        <files>
            <fileset dir="src">
                 <includes name="**/*"/>
            </fileset>
        <files>
</target>
```

Comment: That's the one, thanks! Also thanks for pointing out I can refer to `<files/>` directly rather than via `refid`.